# How do I explain why I upvoted a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

To give the example which caused me to ask this, here's a comment [Find if a string has all unique chars using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226722/find-if-a-string-has-all-unique-chars-using-recursion#comment-44818054).

My thought process was that I wanted to give the guy some credit for actually going away and writing a test class and measuring the performance of his suggested solution.

So I up-voted the comment, then started to write my own comment "+1 for writing a test case..." to explain why, as it wasn't the comment per se I was up-voting, but the work required behind it. The comment system didn't let me add this, because it clearly breaks the:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.
>   Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

So how/where do I explain why I up-voted something, if I don't feel the vote itself conveys sufficient information?

Comments seem to be the accepted place for this (see the number of "down voter care to explain...?" comments), but what I was going to write in the comment clearly goes directly against the guidelines.

Comment: ++1 for the opportunity to demonstrate a cheesy way to circumvent the comment system?

Comment: Just write "I upvoted your comment and I expect you to reward me with a check for $100."  I doubt that the system will complain about that at all.

Comment: Don't tell them you upvoted. Just give a specific compliment if you want to. The upvote then is implied. :-)

Comment: @Compass `error: lvalue required as increment operand`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A great way to express appreciation for something is to explain *why* you found it helpful:

- Thanks! That didn't work at all, but it did help me recognize an unrelated mistake that was causing the problem.
- Thanks! I'm still lost - how do you make a function in C again?
- Thanks! Your solution blew up my house and killed my dog. I don't recommend anyone else trying it.
- Thanks! Your last comment was directly responsible for the destruction of The Universe. I never liked it anyway.
- Thanks! I was afraid I would have to ask a separate question, but thanks to you the solution to my second problem is now locked away in a hard-to-find comment thread!

Or [as Maxpm wrote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment/126183#126183):

> Thank-you comments are okay if they provide **useful feedback.**  Just saying "Great answer!" is pointless and redundant; that is exactly what upvotes are for.  **Comments are for  conveying ideas that upvotes are too general for.**  If you have that kind of praise for someone, then go ahead.

Comment: Maybe the system should not disallow comments like "+1 for (reasonably long explanation)" then? Such comments mean the same as "Thanks! (reasonably long explanation)".

Comment: Already works that way, @Blorgbeard

Comment: Oh, well, good then! :P

Comment: Is this linked to rep, or different on meta? I just tried to add "+1 for taking the time to write a test class and try it!" again as a comment , and it was rejected?

Comment: It is different on meta.